# Accessing class inside jar in ear from another ear

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, war, ear

hi is it possible to access jar files in one ear from another ear? Say I have App1.ear inside that there is a webapp1.war and inside that there is a app1jar.jar and it contains Foo.class. Now say I have App2.ear inside that that there is a Webapp2.war. Is it possible to access Foo.class from webapp2.war?

if possible what configuration change I need to do? I am not getting what I need to search in-order to find this so i posted here.

Comment: This is non-standard, application-server-specific configuration. Which application server are you using?

Comment: is it not possible to do in server independent way?

Comment: Instead of bundling in the war file you could add app1jar.jar as an endorsed jar to the container. It's then available to all installed apps.

Comment: The endorsed jar is an option, but you will have to restart the entire container when you need to change this file. Additionally every deployed application will have access to this code, which may not be appropriate.

Comment: It's asking for trouble: What's the use case for *not* embedding it into *each* individual .ear file?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about weblogic You could define B.ear as a shared application library and access it from A
Similar thing can be done in jboss and weblogic

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#i1065356